# How can access base Site URL id into ajax and pass to controller using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter

I want to access base URL ID into AJAX, within I also pass another id to the controller in Codeigniter. At the controller side, I access two different id one `site_url` id and another s_id.

So how can I achieve this task?

`Site URL`

https://www.demoexample.com=?uid=10

`Ajax` script

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#member_type').on('change',function(){

        var memId = $(this).val();

        if(memId!=''){
                       $.ajax({

                               url: "<?php echo site_url('index.php/template/vehicle/get_member_type')?>",

                               method:'POST',
                               data:'member_id='+memId, // here I want to access site_url id and s_id from drop-down id

                               success:function(data)
                               {
                                  $('#mid').html(data);

                               }
                             }); 
        }
        else{
           $('#mid').html('<option value="">Select sttxt_Standard first</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller `.php` file

```
   function show_vehicle_reg(){   

            $id=$this->input->post('id'); // access multiple id over here from ajax

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: show us your code so we can see your mistake portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax:
`GET` Method

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    complete: function () {
    },
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/cmethod/'.$s_id); ?>",
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

`POST` Method

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    complete: function () {
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('controller/cmethod'); ?>",
    data: ({member_id: memId}),
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```